How to find the deepest path with maximum value for each layer of relationship in Neo4j?
For a given group of nodes, for each node, find its deepest path for relation R. The relation R has a property called weight. Also, for each layer of relations, always select the relation with the max weight value. Then return the start node, second last node and the last node for each path.
I could only write this following code,I do not know how to implement the maximum value part:
with ['abc','def','wqe'] as names

match p=(A)-[:R*0..]->(B)-[:R]->(C)
where A.name in names and xxx 
return A.name,B.name,C.name

For example,
A-[r1:R]->B-[r2:R]->C-[r3:R]->D
A-[r1:R]->B-[r2:R]->C-[r6:R]->K
A-[r4:R]->E-[r5:R]->F

r1.weight is 20
r2.weight is 30
r3.weight is 40
r4.weight is 10
r5.weight is 80
r6.weight is 70

For the first layer, because r1.weight>r4.weight, so r1.weight is the maximum value, so we go for A-[r1:R]->B. So we can just ignore A-[r4:R]->E-[r5:R]->F
For the second layer, r2.weight is the maximum value, keep going.
For the third layer, r3.weight<r6.weight, so r6.weight is the maximum value.
So finally the A-[r1:R]->B-[r2:R]->C-[r6:R]->K is the path we want, and return A,C,K. Then perform the same process for the rest of the nodes in the names list.
Each layer's relation weight is evaluated independently. Only the relations within the same layer (i.e., from the same source node) are compared, and the one with the maximum weight is selected. Cross-layer or cross-branch comparisons do not occur. For example, we only compare (r1 and r4) or (r3 and r6), we do not compare (r1 and r2) or (r1 and r5)
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I know apoc plugin may solve this, but I am not good at it.

Is the second block in your example the definition of the full network, taken together with the third block of weights? How is this a Python question? The problem seems odd due to the requirement for the weight at each distance from the root being more important than the overall weight of the path - it's also unclear whether a weight at a certain level would be preferred in one branch if it would be compared to a weight in a separate branch.

Yes, the second block and the third block are together. The probelm focus on the weight on each layer instead of the overall weight of the whole path.

Each layer's relation weight is evaluated independently. Only the relations within the same layer (i.e., from the same source node) are compared, and the one with the maximum weight is selected. Cross-layer or cross-branch comparisons do not occur.  For example, we only compare (r1 and r4), we do not compare (r1 and r2) or (r1 and r5)

If the max weight at a layer is shared by multiple relationships, do you want to pick one arbitrarily or follow all of them? Or is this guaranteed to be impossible with your data?

Just pick one, there could be two or mroe equal maximum weights, but most of the time there is only one @cybersam
